# Como ordenar un array en base a un array ordenado previamente

Tags: javascript, array, arraylist, ordenamiento

quería saber si es posible ordernar un array en base a otro array ya ordenado. Estoy practicando javascript y tengo una lista de elementos, esa lista quiero que se ordene alfabeticamente y posteriormente con array.reverse  hacer que el orden alfabetico quede al revez pero cuando lo hago solo puedo lograr que el array original haga el reverse y no el ordenado alfabeticamente ya que no tengo idea como hacer para incluir el array ya ordenado en la funcion del array reverse. Espero me puedan ayudar y muchas gracias.

> Cita en bloque

```js
const premium = ["Mercedes", "Ferrari", "Lotus",  "Lexus", "Lamborghini", "Bugatti", "Rolls Royce", "Aston Martin" ];

const basic= ["Toyota", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Fiat"];


function mylistp()  {
let pLen = premium.length;
let text = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + premium[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
console.log (text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}


                                                                                                                                                                     
function mylistorderedp()  {
  console.log("premium ordered")
    let pLen = premium.length;
    var p = [...premium];
    
    p.sort();
    
    let text = "<ul>";
    for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
      text += "<li>" + p[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }

    function mylistreversep()  {
      console.log("reverse")
        let pLen = premium.length;
       var p=premium;
        p.reverse();

        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + p[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";
        
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
       }
    


       function mylistb()  {
        let bLen = basic.length;
        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < bLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=text;
        }
        


function mylistorderedb()  {
  console.log("ordered")
    let pLen = basic.length;
    var b= basic
    let text = "<ul>";
    for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
      text += "<li>" + b[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
    basic.sort();}

    function mylistreverseb()  {
        let pLen = basic.length;
        
        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";
        
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
        basic.reverse();}
```

```css
body {width: 100vw; height: auto; box-sizing: border-box; background:linear-gradient(rgba(211, 195, 16, 0.233),rgba(224, 7, 7, 0.4)) no-repeat center center fixed ; border:border-box; clear: both; margin: 0;}
h1 {text-align: center; font-size: calc(5em - 3.33vw); font-family:'Roboto Slab' ;}

p {text-align: justify; text-indent: 3em; font-size:calc(3em - 1.33vw); margin: 0 2em;}

hr {border-color: black; max-width: 200px;}
.container {  width: 100vw ; display: flex;flex-direction: column; align-content: center;  align-items: center; height:auto; }

h2 {text-align: center;}

.main {width: auto; border: 3px black double; margin: 5rem 2rem; }

.mybuttons {background-color: orangered; border-radius: 2em; width: 10rem; height: 1em; color: white; font-size: 1em;  padding: 1em; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}



.Cars-container {display: flex; width: 100vw; margin-top: 1em ; margin-bottom: 5rem; flex-wrap: wrap; }

.Cars-list {display:flex ; flex-direction: column;  width: 50%;  align-items: center; margin-top: 5em; align-content: center;}

.order {display: flex; margin-top: 2em;}

.sort {all:unset ;}

.sort:last-child {margin-left: 2em;}

.tittles-container {margin-bottom: 5rem;}



li {list-style: url(./car-side-solid.svg); font-size: calc(0.5em + 1.10vw); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em;    }


/* @media all and (max-width:800px)
{
    #two { margin-top: 5em; position: absolute;  top:0%; }
}
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital@1&family=Poppins:wght@300&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,500&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eff657ebaa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Driving test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <div class="tittles-container">
        
        <h1>This is your check up test for driving </h1> <hr>
        
        <div class="main"> 
            <p>Be careful with the instructions to make this process easier. Then confirm your age and you will get a car where you will get your first experience driving our new model bmw with our drive instructors.  </p> </div>
        </div>
        
<!--         <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
 -->  

 <h2> Available cars list</h2>
 <hr>

  <div class=" Cars-container"> 
    
<div class="Cars-list">
<button id="Premium" onclick="mylistp()" class="mybuttons">Premium  Cars</button>  
<div class="order">
<div class="sort"><button onclick="mylistorderedp()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
<div class="sort"> <button onclick="mylistreversep()">Sort reverse</button></div>
</div>
</div>

    <p id="demo"></p> 


<div class="Cars-list" id="two">
<button id="Basic" onclick="mylistb()" class="mybuttons"> Basic Cars</button>
<div class="order">    
<div class="sort"><button  onclick="mylistorderedb()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
<div class="sort"><button  onclick="mylistreverseb()">Sort reverse</button> </div>
</div>
</div>
    <p id="demo2"></p> 
    
</div>



 <script rel="txt/script" src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Como queres ordenar los autos premiums con la funcion reverse? primero ordenarlos alfabéticamente y luego hacer el reverse?

Comment: Tienes que crear un [mre] y con bastante énfasis en "mínimo". Por ejemplo el css no aporta nada a tu pregunta, así como otras funciones JS que lo único que hacen es complicar el entender la situación

Answer (score 2):

Estás cometiendo dos errores en la siguientes líneas:

```
var p = premium;
p.reverse();
```

El primer error es asumir que [`Array.reverse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) primero te ordena el contenido de la matriz y luego le da la vuelta.

El segundo es asumir que `Array.reverse()`, al igual que [`Array.sort()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort), modifica el orden de la matriz origen. Pero, por el contrario, devuelve una referencia **a una nueva matriz** con el orden invertido.

Por lo que la manera correcta de hacer uso del método `reverse()` es de la siguiente manera:

```
var p = premium.sort().reverse();
```

Donde primero se ordena el contenido de `premium` y, en segundo lugar, se obtiene una matriz con los datos en orden inverso que es finalmente asignada a la variable `p`.

Por último, te recomiendo que estas operaciones las hagas una única vez tras obtener los datos, ahorrando tiempo de proceso y optimizando el uso de memoria del navegador:

```
/* Ordenamos la matriz antes de asignarla a "premium" */
const premium = [
    "Mercedes",
    "Ferrari",
    "Lotus",
    "Lexus",
    "Lamborghini",
    "Bugatti",
    "Rolls Royce",
    "Aston Martin",
].sort();
/* Calculamos una única vez la matriz con orden inverso */
const premiumInverso = premium.reverse();
```

Answer (score 0):

Podes hacer que cada vez que llamas a las funciones que ordenan los autos premium se genere una copia local del array original dentro ellas, para la función que ordena alfabéticamente en forma ascendente usas `Array.sort()` sobre dicha copia, para la que ordena alfabéticamente pero en forma descendente usas `Array.sort().reverse()`, estas copias locales son destruidas al salir de la función y no modifican el array original.

```js
const premium = [
  "Mercedes",
  "Ferrari",
  "Lotus",
  "Lexus",
  "Lamborghini",
  "Bugatti",
  "Rolls Royce",
  "Aston Martin",
];

const basic = ["Toyota", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Fiat"];

function mylistp() {
  let pLen = premium.length;
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + premium[i] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function mylistorderedp() {
  console.log("premium ordered");
  let ordered = [...premium];
  ordered.sort();
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < ordered.length; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + ordered[i] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";

  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function mylistreversep() {
  console.log("reverse");
  let revOrdered = [...premium];
  revOrdered.sort().reverse();
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < revOrdered.length; i++) text += "<li>" + revOrdered[i] + "</li>";
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
}

function mylistb() {
  let bLen = basic.length;
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < bLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
}

function mylistorderedb() {
  console.log("ordered");
  let pLen = basic.length;
  var b = basic;
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
    text += "<li>" + b[i] + "</li>";
  }
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
  basic.sort();
}

function mylistreverseb() {
  let pLen = basic.length;
  let text = "<ul>";
  for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
  text += "</ul>";
  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
  basic.reverse();
}
```

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: auto;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: linear-gradient(rgba(211, 195, 16, 0.233), rgba(224, 7, 7, 0.4))
    no-repeat center center fixed;
  border: border-box;
  clear: both;
  margin: 0;
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: calc(5em - 3.33vw);
  font-family: "Roboto Slab";
}

p {
  text-align: justify;
  text-indent: 3em;
  font-size: calc(3em - 1.33vw);
  margin: 0 2em;
}

hr {
  border-color: black;
  max-width: 200px;
}
.container {
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: auto;
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.main {
  width: auto;
  border: 3px black double;
  margin: 5rem 2rem;
}

.mybuttons {
  background-color: orangered;
  border-radius: 2em;
  width: 10rem;
  height: 1em;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.Cars-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100vw;
  margin-top: 1em;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.Cars-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  margin-top: 5em;
  align-content: center;
}

.order {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 2em;
}

.sort {
  all: unset;
}

.sort:last-child {
  margin-left: 2em;
}

.tittles-container {
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

li {
  list-style: url(./car-side-solid.svg);
  font-size: calc(0.5em + 1.1vw);
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}

/* @media all and (max-width:800px)
{
    #two { margin-top: 5em; position: absolute;  top:0%; }
}
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
  <link
    href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital@1&family=Poppins:wght@300&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,500&family=Rubik&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eff657ebaa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Driving test</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="tittles-container">

    <h1>This is your check up test for driving </h1>
    <hr>

    <div class="main">
      <p>Be careful with the instructions to make this process easier. Then confirm your age and you will get a car
        where you will get your first experience driving our new model bmw with our drive instructors. </p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <h2> Available cars list</h2>
  <hr>

  <div class=" Cars-container">

    <div class="Cars-list">
      <button id="Premium" onclick="mylistp()" class="mybuttons">Premium Cars</button>
      <div class="order">
        <div class="sort"><button onclick="mylistorderedp()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
        <div class="sort"> <button onclick="mylistreversep()">Sort reverse</button></div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <p id="demo"></p>


    <div class="Cars-list" id="two">
      <button id="Basic" onclick="mylistb()" class="mybuttons"> Basic Cars</button>
      <div class="order">
        <div class="sort"><button onclick="mylistorderedb()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
        <div class="sort"><button onclick="mylistreverseb()">Sort reverse</button> </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <p id="demo2"></p>

  </div>

  <script rel="text/javascript" src="scripts2.js"></script>
  
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que siempre estás trabajando con el array original, sin modificar, con pocos cambios, tu código funciona de maravilla.
En las funciones **mylistorderedp** y **mylistreversep** borramos la variable **p** y trabajamos directamente con **premiun** de esta forma, cuando ordenas alfabeticamente, **premiun** queda ordenado alfabeticamente, y cuando le das a **reverse** estás invirtiendo el array ordenado.

```js
const premium = ["Mercedes", "Ferrari", "Lotus",  "Lexus", "Lamborghini", "Bugatti", "Rolls Royce", "Aston Martin" ];

const basic= ["Toyota", "Ford", "Chevrolet", "Fiat"];


function mylistp()  {
let pLen = premium.length;
let text = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + premium[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
console.log (text);
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=text;
}
                                                                                                                                                                     
function mylistorderedp()  {
  console.log("premium ordered")
    let pLen = premium.length;        
    premium.sort();          
    let text = "<ul>";
    for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
      text += "<li>" + premium[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";        
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
  }

    function mylistreversep()  {
      console.log("reverse")
        let pLen = premium.length;
        premium.reverse();
        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + premium[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";            
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text;
       }
    


       function mylistb()  {
        let bLen = basic.length;
        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < bLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML=text;
        }
        


function mylistorderedb()  {
  console.log("ordered")
    let pLen = basic.length;
    var b= basic
    let text = "<ul>";
    for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
      text += "<li>" + b[i] + "</li>";
    }
    text += "</ul>";
    
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
    basic.sort();}

    function mylistreverseb()  {
        let pLen = basic.length;
        
        let text = "<ul>";
        for (let i = 0; i < pLen; i++) {
          text += "<li>" + basic[i] + "</li>";
        }
        text += "</ul>";
        
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = text;
        basic.reverse();}
```

```css
body {width: 100vw; height: auto; box-sizing: border-box; background:linear-gradient(rgba(211, 195, 16, 0.233),rgba(224, 7, 7, 0.4)) no-repeat center center fixed ; border:border-box; clear: both; margin: 0;}
h1 {text-align: center; font-size: calc(5em - 3.33vw); font-family:'Roboto Slab' ;}

p {text-align: justify; text-indent: 3em; font-size:calc(3em - 1.33vw); margin: 0 2em;}

hr {border-color: black; max-width: 200px;}
.container {  width: 100vw ; display: flex;flex-direction: column; align-content: center;  align-items: center; height:auto; }

h2 {text-align: center;}

.main {width: auto; border: 3px black double; margin: 5rem 2rem; }

.mybuttons {background-color: orangered; border-radius: 2em; width: 10rem; height: 1em; color: white; font-size: 1em;  padding: 1em; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: center;}



.Cars-container {display: flex; width: 100vw; margin-top: 1em ; margin-bottom: 5rem; flex-wrap: wrap; }

.Cars-list {display:flex ; flex-direction: column;  width: 50%;  align-items: center; margin-top: 5em; align-content: center;}

.order {display: flex; margin-top: 2em;}

.sort {all:unset ;}

.sort:last-child {margin-left: 2em;}

.tittles-container {margin-bottom: 5rem;}



li {list-style: url(./car-side-solid.svg); font-size: calc(0.5em + 1.10vw); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; line-height: 1.5em;    }


/* @media all and (max-width:800px)
{
    #two { margin-top: 5em; position: absolute;  top:0%; }
}
 */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Josefin+Sans:ital@1&family=Poppins:wght@300&family=Roboto+Slab:wght@100;200;300&family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,300;0,500;1,500&family=Rubik&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/eff657ebaa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <title>Driving test</title>
</head>
<body>
    
    
    <div class="tittles-container">
        
        <h1>This is your check up test for driving </h1> <hr>
        
        <div class="main"> 
            <p>Be careful with the instructions to make this process easier. Then confirm your age and you will get a car where you will get your first experience driving our new model bmw with our drive instructors.  </p> </div>
        </div>
        
<!--         <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.js"></script>
 -->  

 <h2> Available cars list</h2>
 <hr>

  <div class=" Cars-container"> 
    
<div class="Cars-list">
<button id="Premium" onclick="mylistp()" class="mybuttons">Premium  Cars</button>  
<div class="order">
<div class="sort"><button onclick="mylistorderedp()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
<div class="sort"> <button onclick="mylistreversep()">Sort reverse</button></div>
</div>
</div>

    <p id="demo"></p> 


<div class="Cars-list" id="two">
<button id="Basic" onclick="mylistb()" class="mybuttons"> Basic Cars</button>
<div class="order">    
<div class="sort"><button  onclick="mylistorderedb()">Sort Alphabetically</button></div>
<div class="sort"><button  onclick="mylistreverseb()">Sort reverse</button> </div>
</div>
</div>
    <p id="demo2"></p> 
    
</div>



 <script rel="txt/script" src="scripts.js"></script>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

No entiendo muy bien a que te refieres ordenar 1 array dependiendo del otro, no me quedo claro ni en la descripción ni en el código. Pero si lo que quieres es ordenar un array y luego invertirlo, puedes hacerlo todo en 1 paso y no en 2. Puedes ordenarlo de forma descendiente y ya quedaría listo

```js
  const array = ["Mercedes", "Ferrari", "Lotus",  "Lexus", "Lamborghini", "Bugatti", "Rolls Royce", "Aston Martin" ]
  array.sort((a,b)=> {
    if(a<b) return 1;
    if(a>b) return -1;
    return 0;
  })

  console.log(array);
```